# Parsing multiple HTML tables into a multidimensional array

Tags: jquery, multidimensional-array

I have scoured and been unable to find the best way to parse multiple HTML tables into a multidimensional array. Basically I have this HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> T1 Row 1 Col 1</td>
    <td> T1 Row 1 Col 2</td>
    <td> T1 Row 1 Col 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> T1 Row 2 Col 1</td>
    <td> T1 Row 2 Col 2</td>
    <td> T1 Row 2 Col 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td> T2 Row 1 Col 1</td>
    <td> T2 Row 1 Col 2</td>
    <td> T2 Row 1 Col 3</td>
    <td> T2 Row 1 Col 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> T2 Row 2 Col 1</td>
    <td> T2 Row 2 Col 2</td>
    <td> T2 Row 2 Col 3</td>
    <td> T2 Row 2 Col 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I would like to automatically convert this into a multidimensional array whereas:

```
$pageTables array would return a length of 2 (tables)
$pageTables[1] would return a length of 2 (rows)
$pageTables[1][0] would return a length of 4 (columns)
$pageTables[0][1][2] would return a value of " T1 Row 2 Col 3"
```

The pages this would run on could have any number of tables and those tables could have differing column counts. The logic I'll be applying later to format the tables will depend on the number of columns.

I know this is likely easy, I just can't for the life of me get it to work.

This is what I've come up with so far, but of course doesn't work:

```
var data = Array();

    $("table").each(function(i, v){
        data[i] = Array();
        $(this).children('tr').each(function(ii, vv){
            data[i][ii] = Array();
                $(this).children('td').each(function(iii, vvv){
                    data[i][ii][iii] = $(this).text();
                }); 
        });    
   })`
```

Comment: There is no automatically.... it will have to be coded... show your best attempt so far. Also, why do you think you need an array? There is a good chance you already have what you need with the tables themselves.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: Are you simply trying to create a reference array to easily access the elements to then pass onto your logic?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I managed to figure out a way on my own. Looks like .find instead of .Children helped.

```
var $data = Array();

$("table").each(function(i, v){
  $data[i] = Array();
  $(this).find('tr').each(function(ii, vv){
    $data[i][ii] = Array();
    $(this).find('td').each(function(iii, vvv){
      $data[i][ii][iii] = $(this).text();
      console.log("Table "+ (i+1) +", Row "+ (ii+1) +", Cell "+ (iii+1) +": " + $data[i][ii][iii]);
    }); 
  }); 
})
```

Testing the above appears to work:

```
console.log("Number of tables: " + $data.length);
console.log("Number of rows in Table 1: " + $data[0].length);
console.log("Number of rows in Table 2: " + $data[1].length);
console.log("Number of cells/cols in Table 1 Row 1: " + $data[0][0].length);
console.log("Number of cells/cols in Table 2 Row 1: " + $data[1][0].length);
console.log($data[0][1][2]);
```

I'm sure there are better ways to do this, so please feel free to respectfully comment.

https://jsfiddle.net/pdowden/m6fhmcbs/